# why xml file is no working with executable le jar

Tags: java, eclipse, executable-jar

I have server.XML file in my eclipse project which, on executing from eclipse, is working fine.

But when I create executable jar using ***package all files*** option its not able to access that XML file,even if its present in ***resource*** folder within jar.

Why is this happening? 
How to do it?

I am accessing XML file by this way:

```
private void initializeDocument()
{

    try {
        docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        /*  
        URL xmlResource = getClass().getResource("/server.xml");
        File xmlFile = new File(xmlResource.getPath());
         */
        //
        document = docBuilder.parse (new File("ServerResources/server.xml"));
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SAXException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }



}
```

Comment: You need to open the resource as a resource, not as a file, by using "getResourceAsStream" or similar.

Comment: are you going to pack a server.xml to your jar file ? and going to access it from your jar ?

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is this line:

```
File xmlFile = new File(xmlResource.getPath());
```

A resource inside a JAR *is not a file*.

Instead, you have to use `getClass().getResourceAsStream()` ans use the `DocumentBuilder` with that stream.

Answer (score -1):

try this snippet of code...

let me know if it works...

```
String fileURI = this.getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();
    fileURI = fileURI.substring(0, fileURI.length()-4);
    fileURI = fileURI+"ServerResources/server.xml";
    String actualFileURI= URLDecoder.decode(fileURI);

    document = docBuilder.parse (new File(actualFileURI));
```